# Cannot boot windows 10 usb from my desktop, but can from laptop

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, arch-linux, manjaro

Basically the title. I've been trying to get my computer to boot from my USB, but when I pick it from the boot options it quickly then goes to the "insert bootable media" black screen. I've tried both legacy and UEFI boot settings, and have secure boot off. I've also upgraded my system with pacman -Syyu, and flashed my bios with up-to-date software. I know that this question has been asked several times, but I can't find an answer that fixes my problem. Hoping for any amount of guidance for what I should try next.

In case it's important, I'm running 4.14 manjaro, trying to install Windows 10.

Comment: Your title is confusing. By "computer" do you mean "desktop"?

Comment: @InterLinked yes, sorry. I've updated the title.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and I want to answer for future readers. Turns out Gigabyte motherboards have a history of trouble when it comes to booting from USBs. Simply burning the ISO on a CD instead worked.

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3274358/gigabyte-usb-boot-concerns.html may help with that.  It sounds to be due to bios settings for usb2 and usb3 legacy